# How to finish this python dictionary transformation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a python dictionary `parsed_dict`.

```
{
    "Field name 1": {
        "item1": -0.05,
        "item2": -0.06,
        "item3": -0.07,
    },
    "Field name 2": {
        "item1": -0.01,
        "item2": -0.02,
        "item3": -0.03,
    },
    "Field name 3": {
        "item1": -0.05,
        "item2": -0.06,
        "item3": -0.07,
    }
}
```

I would like to transform it into another dictionary `new_dict` that looks like this;

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "key": "name",
            "label": "name",
            "sortable": true
        },  
        {
            "key": "item1",
            "label": "item1",
            "sortable": true
        },
        {
            "key": "item2",
            "label": "item2",
            "sortable": true
        },
        {
            "key": "item3",
            "label": "item3",
            "sortable": true
        }
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Field name 1",
            "item1": -0.05,
            "item2": -0.06,
            "item3": -0.07
        },
        {
            "name": "Field name 2", 
            "item1": -0.01,
            "item2": -0.02,
            "item3": -0.03
        },
        {
            "name": "Field name 3", 
            "item1": -0.05,
            "item2": -0.06,
            "item3": -0.07
        }
    ]
}
```

I finally managed to find almost the right solution to fill up "items". Even then, my solution is not 100% right because the `"name"` is at the bottom of "items", not at the top. Here is my code;

```
for value in parsed_dict.values():
    new_dict["items"].append(value)
for i, key in enumerate(parsed_dict.keys()):
    new_dict["items"][i]["name"] = key
```

I am stuck for a long time at figuring out how to fill up `"fields"`.

I am using python 3.9

Comment: The dictionary are values to be filled up in a table. There is nothing wrong. The "field" keys are the names of the table columns.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have edited the code to fit your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer would be very close to your previous [question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71275149/how-to-transform-this-python-dictionary-to-this-other-dictionary-format). The only difference is to assign the `key` value to the `value["name"]` in the loop. You can try what follows:

```py
new_dict = {"fields":[], "items":[]}
checkFields = []
for key, value in parsed_dict.items():
  value["name"] = key
  new_dict["items"].append(value)
  for itemKey in value.keys():
    if itemKey not in checkFields:
      tempFieldDict = {"key":itemKey, "label":itemKey, "sortable": "true"}
      checkFields.append(itemKey)
      new_dict["fields"].append(tempFieldDict)
new_dict
```

The `new_dict` variable will result in the following output:

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "key": "item1",
            "label": "item1",
            "sortable": "true"
        },
        {
            "key": "item2",
            "label": "item2",
            "sortable": "true"
        },
        {
            "key": "item3",
            "label": "item3",
            "sortable": "true"
        },
        {
            "key": "name",
            "label": "name",
            "sortable": "true"
        }
    ],
    "items": [
        {
            "item1": -0.05,
            "item2": -0.06,
            "item3": -0.07,
            "name": "Field name 1"
        },
        {
            "item1": -0.01,
            "item2": -0.02,
            "item3": -0.03,
            "name": "Field name 2"
        },
        {
            "item1": -0.05,
            "item2": -0.06,
            "item3": -0.07,
            "name": "Field name 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @user781486 Thanks for the note. I edited the answer as per your comment.

Answer (score -2):

I will answer my own question for the sake of completion. It is built on top of the good answer by @Amirhossein Kiani.

The extra modification is to shift last element of "fields" and "items" to the beginning as required in the question.

```
new_dict = {"fields":[], "items":[]}
checkFields = []
for key, value in parsed_dict.items():
  value["name"] = key
  new_dict["items"].append(value)
  for itemKey in value.keys():
    if itemKey not in checkFields:
      tempFieldDict = {"key":itemKey, "label":itemKey, "sortable": "true"}
      checkFields.append(itemKey)
      new_dict["fields"].append(tempFieldDict)
# Add the 2 lines below to shift last element of "fields" and "items" to the beginning.     
new_dict["fields"].insert(0, new_dict["fields"].pop())
new_dict["items"].insert(0, new_dict["items"].pop())
```

Comment: Error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'insert'` using this code

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I made a mistake. My answer was built on answer from @Amirhossein Kiani who has the right answer. I copied and pasted the wrong code segment which is from your answer. I have corrected the mistake.